# Pictures on \fancyhead will show out of place

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I'm working on the translation of a baroque book replete with a variety of ornaments, some of which are appended to the header.

[image: Original ornament on header]

I have already rasterized them, created `.png` files and attempted to include them in the `\fancyhead` command of fancyhdr package, as in thus:

```
\fancyhead[CO, CE]{%
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Ornament2.jpg}% Ornament to the left %
({\hspace{.1cm}}\thepage{\hspace{.1cm}})% Page numbering within parenthesis %
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Ornament2.jpg}% Ornament to the right %
}
```

But they will show up way out of their place. Not only that as the header itself is completely deformed. I have tried the following solutions:

- `\parbox` to wrap the picture;
- the `figure` environment around `\includegraphics`;
- converting the `.png` into `.pdf` and including it;
- using `\chead[]{}` instead;
- altering the `\headheight` parameter, as well as with the `geometry` package;
- using `\protect` before `\includegraphics`,

but all of these to no avail, each one producing an anomaly of its own.

If anyone has got any other suggestions, I'd appreciate them.

**Obs.:** it might be possible to introduce them as background images, but the fact they change every chapter has convinced otherwise.

**Obs2.:** perhaps it'd be possible to convert the ornaments into a new font of some kind and use `\fontspec` to place them?

**Obs3.:** I'm using the `book` class.

Answer (score 1):

Without your images, this is my best guess.  Generally speaking, `\usebox` is faster than `\includegraphics` (no file I/O or conversion needed). `\raisebox` compensates for the baseline difference between images and text. Using `\makebox` will keep the width constant as the page numbers change.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{graphicx} %vectorgraphics 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancyhead[C]{% simple but slow
%\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image-a}% Ornament to the left %
%\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}{(\hspace{.1cm}\thepage\hspace{.1cm})}% Page numbering within parenthesis %
%\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image-b}% Ornament to the right %
%}
\newsavebox{\lefthdr}
\newsavebox{\righthdr}
\savebox{\lefthdr}{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image-a}}(}
\savebox{\righthdr}{)\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{example-image-b}}}
\fancyhead[C]{\usebox\lefthdr\makebox[1.3em]{\thepage}\usebox\righthdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I just had to combine the two codes, since the first one seemed to require a box for the picture, rather than the page numbering. Here's what it looked like in the end: `\fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{Picture}(\hspace{.1cm}\thepage\hspace{.1cm})\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{Picture}}
}`

Comment: Just make sure \headheight is at least the height of the picture at [scale=1].  You can compare the two using `\the\headheight` and `\sbox0{...}\the\ht0`.  BTW, scale=1 is the default.

Comment: Just a question, why did you use the negative depth of \strutbox as the lift parameter of \raisebox? That's what -\dp\strutbox means, isn't it?

Comment: Lowering the image raises the baseline.  \dp\strutbox is the distance between the baseline for text and the bottom of a \strut.